# Develop a GEF4 rcp application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I have been using eclipse GEF 3.x for developing graphical editors. While there are many examples for this framework, GEF4 doesn't seem to have many. Since gef4 is rewritten based on Java fx, putting up more examples will popularize the framework. For instance after doing lot of searching I found out that `IVisualPart` Is used instead of `IEditorPart`. Any pointers to a comprehensive example would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GEF repository at [GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/gef) contains examples for the individual components, i.a. the "MVC Logo Example" that demonstrates usage of the MVC technology stack that is offered by GEF for the development of graphical applications, and the "Zest Graph Example" that demonstrates usage of the Zest technology stack that is offered by GEF for the development of graph-based graphical applications.

Moreover, you can register for a free GEF tutorial here: https://info.itemis.com/en/gef/tutorials/

The terminology was changed from IEditPart and IEditPolicy to IVisualPart and IPolicy. Moreover, IVisualPart is divided into IContentPart, IFeedbackPart, and IHandlePart. For details, take a look at the documentation in the [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/eclipse/gef/wiki), especially the [MVC documentation](https://github.com/eclipse/gef/wiki/MVC).

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I browsed through the examples and they seem to help. I will try them in my machine